# Determine which 'service' is using another 'service'

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

We're using ASP.NET core and are running into the problem, that some registered services (from third-party libraries) request a specific 'service' (based on an interface) that has been deprecated.

The problem is that we don't know which libraries are using this deprecated service interface.

What we've done so far is:

- create a custom implementation for the service interface
- and registered this custom implementation (class) with DI

```
// Registration
services.AddTransient<IServiceInterface>((services) => new CustomCustomService(Log.Logger));

// Custom implementation
internal class CustomService : IServiceInterface
{
  public CustomService (ILogger logger)
  {
    logger.Warning("!!! CustomService is still being used !!!");
  }
}
```

So now we can see that the unwanted service is being used 'somewhere'.

But is it in some way possible to detect for which service the deprecated service has been created?

I've tried listing the stack trace using

```
    var st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    logger.Warning("!!! CustomService is still being used !!!" + Environment.NewLine + "{stacktrace}", st.ToString());
```

But that doesn't seem to give information about the service using the deprecated service...

Comment: Why don't you remove the registration altogether from the ServiceCollection? This will allow the application to fail fast and gives you an exception a message that exactly states which component depends on the missing registration. Because not doing this, means you need to provide the `CustomCustomService` with contextual information about its consumers, which is something that is really hard to achieve with MS.DI.

Comment: OK, dit this and I got one item for which the problem occurs. But now I don't know for sure if I don't have a dependency on the removed service from another service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically - as expected - it's not possible to exactly know which libraries (for which you don't have the code) use a certain dependency.

It's just trial and error ;)

Thanks for the ideas everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```cs
var registrationsDependingOnMyService =
    from descriptor in services
    where descriptor.ImplementationType != null
    let dependencies =
        from ctor in descriptor.ImplementationType!.GetConstructors()
        from param in ctor.GetParameters()
        select param.ParameterType
    where dependencies.Contains(typeof(IServiceInterface))
    select descriptor;
```

This will query the `IServiceCollection` for registrations whose implementation type have a constructor argument of type `IServiceInterface`.

This might not be a bulletproof solution, as types or registrations can more sneakily depend on the service collection (e.g. by calling back into the `IServiceProvider` from within a registration delegate), but this is likely the best you can do with MS.DI.